# Set ignore_port_in_host_matching or strip_any_host_port in Istio EnvoyFilter

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

Related with the issue https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/23650

EnvoyFilter is used to modify the request's host, and re-route request to other host(or so called cluster).

In lua script, if replaced api is the same port with outbound listener's port, replacing host in lua filter works. But with different ports, we cannot re-route the request to other cluster through modifying host header in http request.

As the answer of envoy community, we should use `ignore_port_in_host_matching` or `strip_any_host_port` route configuration in envoy.

But how can we set those configs in istio?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Codes can be found here: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/23650